# npm error: 'specify configs in the ini-formatted file:' \User\.npmrc

Tags: reactjs, npm

NOOB here, trying to follow this React tutorial: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/

The README.md file says to:
    npm install
    node server.js

After cloning the repo, I ran npm install and a bunch of stuff (modules?) downloaded. But when I try to run npm server.js and I'm hit with this message:

```
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\User\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.3.6 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

C:\Users\User\.npmrc contains this: 
key=
```

Any ideas on how to get the npm server up and running? Do I need to set the key in this file to something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the correct way to start the server would be

```
npm run server.js
```

Comment: I am trying to run my project in Android but it is showing me same issue
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\Kalpana\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key=value

And this didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Try out below command if trying to start NextJS react

`npm run-script start`

Answer (score 2):

Use `npx` instead of `npm`:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Please explain why this makes a difference: why exactly does npm not work with node?

Answer (score 1):

try like below command without npm

Ex: `create-react-app app-name` .(without npm)

Answer (score 0):

Steps worked for me

- Create a folder ".npmrc"  under  the  path it is complaining
- Set the cache location using command npm config set cache 'path to npmrc folder' --global
- Try running  npm install  package now

Answer (score 0):

It should be with a space:

```
npm install @angular/material --save
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 2+:

Check the content of the file `package.json` into "scripts", as image below

[image]

Then you would use in terminal:

`npm run ng` or
`npm run start` etc.

In my case I was executing without `run` and becase of this I got the same error as you.

Now, using `run`is ok!