# Docker gives error Specify configs in the ini-formatted file: /root/.npmrc

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, npm, composer-php

When I tried to build docker container, it throws error like

```
2022-11-19 06:26:39 Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
2022-11-19 06:26:39     /root/.npmrc
2022-11-19 06:26:39 or on the command line via: npm  --key=value
2022-11-19 06:26:39 
2022-11-19 06:26:39 More configuration info: npm help config
2022-11-19 06:26:39 Configuration fields: npm help 7 config
2022-11-19 06:26:39 
2022-11-19 06:26:39 npm@8.19.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

. my docker-compose.yml is as follows

```
npm:
    image: node:16
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and provide the full error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm error: 'specify configs in the ini-formatted file:' \User\.npmrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461080/npm-error-specify-configs-in-the-ini-formatted-file-user-npmrc)

Comment: Why is this tagged with Laravel and Composer, but does not contain any such code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?